# Of unicode-math and range setting

Tags: unicode-math

While learning to use `unicode-math` and its options, I tried to compile the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\diff}{\symup{d}}
\newcommand{\npder}[3]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\symbfup{#1}}
\usepackage{luaotfload} %% only for use with LuaTeX
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{STIX2Math.otf}
\setmathfont[range={scr,bfscr},StylisticSet=1]{STIX2Math.otf} %% line A
\setmathfont[range={\int},StylisticSet=8]{STIX2Math.otf} %% line B

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
   \symcal{L} = -\increment\symcal{U} = -q\increment\symcal{V} \\
   \increment\symscr{E} = \symscr{Q} - \symscr{L}
\end{gather*}
\begin{align*}
     &\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{5x+1}{3x^2-x-10} \,\diff{x} = \\
   = &\lim_{\alpha \to 0^+} \left[ \frac{2}{3} \left.\ln\left(3x+5\right)\right|_0^{\frac{1}{\alpha}} + \left.\ln\left(2-x\right)\right|_0^{2-\alpha} + \left.\ln\left(x-2\right)\right|_{2+\alpha}^{\frac{1}{\alpha}} \right] = \\
   = &\lim_{\alpha \to 0^+} -\frac{5}{3}\ln\alpha = +\infty
\end{align*}
\begin{equation*}
   \begin{dcases}
      \nabla^2\vect{E} - \frac{1}{c^2}\npder{2}{\vect{E}}{t} = \vect{0} \\
      \nabla^2\vect{B} - \frac{1}{c^2}\npder{2}{\vect{B}}{t} = \vect{0}
   \end{dcases}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

I'm encountering several problems and I've tracked them to lines A and B, where I declare new options for certain ranges of glyphs. In particular:

- **If I comment both lines:** I get the expected result both with XeTeX and LuaTeX, apart from the known problem of the integral limits
  kerning in LuaTeX (this is why I'd like to compile this with XeTeX,
  which gives the best result).
- **If I only comment line B:** in LuaTeX, still only the integral lower limit displacement, but everything else is as expected; with XeTeX, however, I get several tofu's, exactly where a dotted delimiter is placed.
  [image: LuaTeX final result]

[image: XeTeX final result]

- **If I only comment line A:** I actually get the same result as the previous case, of course with upright integrals and no script letters. I get the XeTeX tofu's as well...
- **If I comment no lines:** I find the exact same result as the previous case, as if line B "overrides" line A and so I can't get both upright integrals and script capitals. Of course, I still get the tofu's with XeTeX.

Where am I getting the "range" part wrong?

P.S.: as a side note, in *each and every case* I got the error `Undefined control sequence \end{align*}`, but the PDF comes out as it was meant to be ...

Comment: Note that the code from which I generated the examples in the pictures was a selection from a much, much longer one. While copying the lines I forgot the definition of `\diff`, and this is why the differential in the integrals is not displayed correctly.

Comment: Regarding the "tofu": https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/344. Regarding the observation that line B overrides line A: https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/331. You could try to swap the lines but imho the range option is more or less broken.

Comment: Thank you for your hints! You're right about swapping the lines: the final call of `\setmathfont` always wins over all the previous ones...

Comment: For the record: I managed to put a "patch" regarding the `range` option...
`\setmathfont{STIX2Math.otf}[StylisticSet=8]
\setmathfont{STIX2Math-sty1.otf}[range={scr},StylisticSet=1]`
where STIX2Math-sty1.otf is a differently-named exact copy of STIX2Math.otf.

Comment: The `range` bug has been fixed with `unicode-math` version 0.8j, released 2018-01-07. In the meantime, also the displacement of limits with LuaLaTeX has been corrected.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no longer relevant as the bugs have been fixed.